# Oracle WebLogic Server JAX-WS Error Codes

Tags: java, wcf, service, web, wcf-security

We are trying to consume a Java Web Service hosted on Oracle WebLogic Server (implemented following JAX-WS specifications) from a `C# WCF 4.0` Client.

The error codes thrown on Server Side Trace is

```
Error codes: 3001 3201 4008 4208 6408 Error code:3001
```

We are unable to figure out what these means ? It seems these are not documented. (We might be wrong or looking at a wrong place).

Comment: Looks like those error codes of the webservice itself. Are you able to do a trace on the WS?

Comment: @Hyangelo You are right Hyangelo. These are from the WebService itself. The JWS team does not have any custom error codes. We have full verbose trace on yet still these are the range of error codes we are running into.